# German Umlaut hash - SHA256 on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, sha256, collation

I am facing a problem when applying SHA256 hash to German Umlaut Characters.

```sql
--Without Umlaut
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','o'), 2) as HASH_ID
Sql server Output 65C74C15A686187BB6BBF9958F494FC6B80068034A659A9AD44991B08C58F2D2
```

This is matching to the output in
https://www.pelock.com/products/hash-calculator

```sql
--With Umlaut

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','ö'), 2)
Sql server Output B0B2988B6BBE724BACDA5E9E524736DE0BC7DAE41C46B4213C50E1D35D4E5F13
Output from pelock: 6DBD11FD012E225B28A5D94A9B432BC491344F3E92158661BE2AE5AE2B8B1AD8
```

I want the SQL server output to match to pelock. I have tested outputs from other sources (Snowflake and python) and all of it aligns with output from pelock. Not sure why SQL server is not giving the right result. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The value from Pelock is a hashed UTF-8 value, the one from SQL Server isn't, it's likely using a ANSI-1252 (I don't know what collation you are using so cannot confirm).

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-GDR) (KB5014355) - 13.0.6419.1 (X64)   May 29 2022 21:05:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: )

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues:

- The literal text itself is being reinterpreted, because you have the wrong database collation. You can use the `N` prefix to prevent that, but this leads to a second problem...
- The value from pelock is UTF-8, but using `N` means it will be UTF-16 `nvarchar`.

So you need to use a UTF-8 binary collation, the `N` prefix *and* cast it back to `varchar`.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',CAST(N'ö' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8 AS varchar(100))), 2)
```

| Result |
| --- |
| 6DBD11FD012E225B28A5D94A9B432BC491344F3E92158661BE2AE5AE2B8B1AD8 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ed204c38a96760254306adaf1dd5a821)

UTF-8 collations are only supported in SQL Server 2019 and later. In older version you would need to find a different collation that deals with the characters you have. It may not be possible to find a collation that deals with all of your data.

Comment: Worth noting that UTF-8 collations are only supported in SQL Server 2019 onwards.

Comment: For some reason I am still getting the old result. My organisation is using SQL server version 18.10

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-GDR) (KB5014355) - 13.0.6419.1 (X64)   May 29 2022 21:05:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: )

Comment: You are, in truth, out of luck then, @CharlesJoseph . I would suggest that perhaps you switch to using UTF-16 in your pelock application.

Comment: I checked the UTF-16 encoding for umlaut 'ö'  https://dencode.com/en/hash but it is still not matching to my server.  CODE: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',N'ö'), 2)    OUTPUT from server: CA36967BDBB71E0D87797C0B0FE9A753BD777E0CB4AB142F7C7CDDDA7EAE6CB4   Output from dencode: 6775ad8bf1895ff2d867c9008219752f8f42c78b5fd101ace5255283b35145c9

Comment: The collation used is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS